# Passing array from php to javascript through ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my first post in stackoverflow. I have always got my answers from previously posted questions. This problem has been bugging me and all the solutions I tried have not worked.

I have a js function which makes an ajax request to get weather info of town passed:

```
var _getWeatherInfo = function(ntown){
  var town = ntown;
  var url = "PHP/weather.php?town=" + town;
  request1.onreadystatechange = _refreshWeatherList();                    
  request1.open("GET", url, true);
  request1.send("");
}
```

I am using the following php code to return the sql results stored in array:

```
<?php
    //Connection to the database
    $mysql = mysql_connect("localhost","xuvaz","x");

    //Selecting Database
    $db = mysql_select_db("weather");

    $town = $_GET['town'];
    $tarray = array();

    $sql1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weather WHERE town='$town'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {
    $tarray =  array('town' => $row['town'],'outlook' => $row['outlook']);
    }

    echo json_encode($tarray);
?>
```

Then I have a function that is called when the request is completed:

```
   var _refreshWeatherList = function() {
        var weather_info = request1.responseText;
        for(var i = 0; i < weather_info.length; i++){
            var wtown = weather_info[i].town;
            var woutlook = weather_info[i].outlook; 
            var wmin = weather_info[i].min_temp;
            var wmax = weather_info[i].max_temp;
        }
        var wLine = new WLine(wtown, woutlook, wmin, wmax);
        _weather.push(wLine);
    _refreshWeatherDisplay();
   }
```

The problem is I cant access the array values.

I can see the values as `{"town":"Christchurch","outlook":"fine"}` in firebug under response.

Even when I use JSON parse it gives error in the firebug , `JSON.parse: unexpected end of data`. If 
I can just access the data my whole project would be completed.

Comment: In firebug, check "network" tab, and take a look at the response of your ajax query, is it clean?

Comment: Your real problem is the JSON parsing issue. What is the exact content of `responseText`? Whatever you're passing to `JSON.parse` is invalid.

Comment: on a side note, please, replace mysql with mysqli, mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: By the way - if this is for production use, you need to fix your PHP to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This is for my assignment in college.
Loïc and Hamish, the content of response is :
{"town":"Dunedin","outlook":"foggy"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code is returning an object (last row from your loop) rather than an array of objects, but your JavaScript is expecting an array.

Change your PHP to the following to appand to `$tarray`:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {
    $tarray[] =  array('town' => $row['town'],'outlook' => $row['outlook']);
}
```

Your JavaScript needs to wait for [readyState = Loaded](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/#dfn-onreadystatechange) and JSON-decode the responseText:

```
var _refreshWeatherList = function() {
    if(request1.readyState == 4) {
        var weather_info = JSON.parse(request1.responseText);
        ....
    }
}
```

If the parse is failing, trying logging it to the console to make sure the PHP isn't returning extra characters.

Comment: Thank you. I just changed it to 
$tarray[] =  $row;
It is returning correctly. It is as following:
[{"town":"Christchurch","outlook":"fine","min_temp":"9","max_temp":"27"}]
But I am not being able to parse it for some reason.

Comment: Did you try adding console.log(request1.responseText) to log the response to the JavaScript console?  Does it look right?

Comment: Thank you Stepan. I found the solution. I have posted it but I dont know how it worked so if u can please explain.

Comment: The readystatechanged event gets fired multiple times.  Only when readystate=4 (Loaded) can you acces the responseText.

I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _refreshWeatherList = function() {
    var weather_info = eval("("+request1.responseText+")");
    for(var i = 0; i < weather_info.length; i++){
        var wtown = weather_info[i].town;
        var woutlook = weather_info[i].outlook; 
        var wmin = weather_info[i].min_temp;
        var wmax = weather_info[i].max_temp;
    }
    var wLine = new WLine(wtown, woutlook, wmin, wmax);
    _weather.push(wLine);
_refreshWeatherDisplay();}
```

'request1.responseText' must be 'object' use eval()     --! my english not well

Comment: Use of `eval` here is not a good use of it, since you're using it to parse JSON data. Instead, use the built-in [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) global object (or a polyfill like [Douglas Crockford's `JSON-js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for older browsers that don't have native `JSON` objects), which gives you the same result without the pitfalls of `eval` here.

Comment: V_V yes! but how to do?

Comment: You can click on the `JSON` link I have in my comment to see the `JSON` MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) article on it. There is plenty of explanation and examples. Here, you will want to use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: To be honest, my English is very difficult to read it, thank you！

Comment: When i use aval to add the brackets, firebug shows syntax error. 
ajp15243: When I use json parse firebug shows this error "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data."

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help. I found the fault. I forgot to include these two lines.

```
if (request1.readyState == 4) {
    if (request1.status == 200){
```